# Odd button on IE

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

Environment: IE11, Windows 7, Domain workstation.

On one workstation only, there is an extra button on the top, to the left of the 'back' arrow. It seems to act as a 'Home' button, but we don't know where this button is coming from - other workstations with the same version of IE, same addons, same et cetera, don't have it. This particular workstation also has other strange behaviors. None of our antimalwareware reports any concerns with this workstation.

Picture below - can anyone clue us in on where this is coming from and how to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: The purpose of the icon cannot be determined from a simple screenshot

Comment: @Ramhound - I was hoping someone else had seen something similar and might offer some ideas. As indicated, it acts as a 'Home' button if clicked. We don't know what's generating it, and whether whatever is generating it is responsible for some other odd behaviours.

Comment: Sounds like something is seriously wrong inside Internet Explorer. There's a "reset to defaults"  button in the settings->advanced. This has solved weird problems in the past. Try it. Also try an sfc /scannow

Comment: Have you tried to reset Internet Explorer?  `Internet Options -> Advanced`.  Please clarify what strange behavior the workstation exhibits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we accidentally solved this - if you have a page displayed, and you click-drag the IE logo in the address bar, it will create a "pinned" shortcut. These shortcuts, when activated, have the IE logo in the box to the left, as shown. The When you have that logo, it's not a *Home* button, it's a button to return you to the "pinned" address.

Answer (score 0):

It might be Classic Shell IE was installed. But why not open IE, go to the gear icon, select the *Manage add-ons* menu item and see what is different about that PC?

[image: Manage add-ons IE]

Comment: The questionable workstation has no addons that the other workstations do not; this was stated in the question - "... same version of IE, same addons, same et cetera, ..."

Comment: The "et cetera" is a very broad thing.  While I don't know what's causing the problem, someone else might.  Fill in the et cetera with all of the research that you've done on the problem station, no matter how insignificant.  If you find the cause, please enter it as an answer to your question.